# WPF Tab Control with multiple tab items

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

Hi I have 2 user WPF user controls which I would like to group together and present on a single tab control.
i.e. have 2 tab items with the 2 user controls. There are also some common buttons for both user controls. Is this feasible, any pointers/samples please. Thanks

Comment: Post your current code and XAML. Post your attempted solution and how it didn't work

Comment: You don't have to put your controls in the tab control, just maintain the visibility of your contorls based on tab changes.